# Minecraft/Node - Writing to process.stdin and Child Process Also Receiving Input

Tags: node.js, minecraft

I'm trying to write a terminal application that would allow me to start and stop a Minecraft server, write arguments through readline that would first be checked by the Node process and then, if determined by the script, sent to the Minecraft server for use instead.

Running on Windows 10 with latest Node build and Minecraft JE server.

First I tested out just starting up a node process that spawned in a child process holding the Minecraft server. I set the 3 stdio arguments to 'inherit' and also 'ipc' (not 100% sure why this is necessary, but I saw others do it). Once run, if I typed anything into the terminal the Minecraft server would receive input through Node. This was great. What I wanted, though, was to be able to run readline and parse inputs and determine whether Node should process the input or if they should be sent to the Minecraft server.

So I played around with the stdio arguments and using process.stdin.write() and such, trying to figure out how to write to the child process' stdin so that the Minecraft server would receive the input, but to no avail.

So I tried running a "master" Node process that would fork a secondary Node process. The "master" would run readline, and use child.send() if any input was to be sent there. Then, in the second Node process, I would start the Minecraft server as a spawn with all 3 stdio arguments set to inherit. I would then listen with process.on('message') and if a message was received, write it to process.stdin hoping the Minecraft process would receive it through inherited input. But this also did not work.

I've tried a number of different things, but in the end I haven't had any luck. I've tried looking up as much as I could, but I haven't found anything that would help me out. Sorry if this ends up being a no-brainer.

```
// First Iteration
// spawns in a minecraft server and listens for input in the terminal
// effectively the same as running the equivalent run command for the minecraft server, except this runs as a Node child process

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
var minecraft = spawn('java',  ['-jar', '-Xms1G','-Xmx1G', '-Dfile.encoding=utf8', '../spigot-1.13.2.jar'], {
    stdio: [
        'inherit',
        'inherit',
        'inherit',
        'ipc'
    ],
})


// Second Iteration
// changed cp stdin to pipe and tried to write manually via rl

const spawn = require('child_process').spawn
const readline = require('readline')
var minecraft = spawn('java',  ['-jar', '-Xms1G','-Xmx1G', '-Dfile.encoding=utf8', '../spigot-1.13.2.jar'], {
    stdio: [
        'pipe',
        'inherit',
        'inherit',
        'ipc'
    ],
})
var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
}).on('line',(line)=> {
    process.stdin.write(line)
})


// Later iterations involved running nested child processes, basically, but were all more or less more-abstract versions of my second iteration.
```

What I'd like to achieve, as I said earlier, is being able to listen for admin input from the terminal with readline and, as appropriate, send that input to the Minecraft server process. Otherwise, readline input would be processed in the Node process.

** to clarify, when I say it doesn't work, what I mean is that I get no response from the Minecraft server process. Nothing in-game, nothing on the command line. With my first iteration, I could see output from the Minecraft process both in-game and on the command line. But by the second iteration, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to `process.stdin`. Did you mean to write to the stdin of the minecraft process `mincraft.stdin`?

```
minecraft.stdin.write(line)
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MeWSg7Vt That script gives me https://pastebin.com/VE6v6N8A when I type in "test".